# Какой код будет работать быстрее?

Tags: pascal

Т.е. вопрос такой: изменение значения переменной через указатель и напрямую занимают одно и тоже время?

```
 var 
 mas: array [0..100] of integer;
 pMas: ^integer;
 mas2: array [0..100] of integer;
 pMas2: ^integer;
 i: integer;

// код №1
pMas := addr(mas);   // быстродействие этой строки считать не будем
pMas2 := addr(mas2); // этой тоже

for i:=1 to 100 do
begin    
    inc(pmas);           // и этой
    inc(pmas2);          // и этой
    pmas2 ^:= pmas^;
end;

// код №2
for i := 1 to 100 do
begin
    mas2[i] := mas[i];
end;
```

Comment: что-то не так с кодировкой

Comment: уже поправил

Comment: вотето я понимаю - забота о скорости работы =)... на последовательном языке

Comment: Доступ к элементам массива фактически происходит по указателю, так что думаю особой разницы нет. А если учесть что во втором цикле один инкремент, а в первом целых три, то второй цикл по идее будет работать быстрее.

Comment: @ололо, запустите 100000 итераций и выведите время. Это так сложно?)

Comment: @Gorets, почему последовательный язык? Вроде паскаль процедурный.

Comment: я к тому что нету там много поточности, весь код выполняется последовательно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что генерирует фри паскаль со включенной оптимизацией (комментарии мои):

```
        mov eax,offset U_P$PROGRAM_MAS ; pMas := addr(mas);
        mov edx,offset U_P$PROGRAM_MAS2 ; pMas2 := addr(mas2);

        ; Первый цикл:
        mov ecx,1 ; i:=1;
        dec ecx
    ALIGN 4
@@j9:
        inc ecx
        add eax,4 ; inc(pmas);
        add edx,4 ; inc(pmas2);
        mov ebx,dword ptr [eax] ; ebx := pmas^;
        mov dword ptr [edx],ebx ; pmas2^ := ebx;
        cmp ecx,100
        jl  @@j9

        ; Второй цикл:
        mov eax,1 ; i := 1
        dec eax
    ALIGN 4
@@j14:
        inc eax
        mov edx,dword ptr [dword ptr U_P$PROGRAM_MAS+eax*4] ; edx := mas[i];
        mov dword ptr [dword ptr U_P$PROGRAM_MAS2+eax*4],edx ; mas2[i] := edx;
        cmp eax,100
        jl  @@j14
```

Comment: Второй цикл лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Теоретически, строка

```
pmas2 ^:= pmas^;
```

быстрее, чем

```
mas2[i] := mas[i];
```

но только потому, что в первом случае часть вычисления адреса вынесена в предыдущие две строчки.

Поэтому в целом оба цикла должны выполняться за одинаковое время. Хотя, если предположить, что инкремент быстрее, чем просто вычисление адреса, то тогда первый цикл тоже будет быстрее.

Comment: Хороший компилятор при высоком уровне оптимизации сделает одинаковый код.